# how do i select this tag in html in jsoup and extract the text

Tags: android

am trying to extract this text  **Factory / Production Operatives** from this html using jsoup kindly tell me what am doing wrong cheers.

```
</td>
                        <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://demourl.uk/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19279943&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20%2f%20Production%20Operatives&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-09T09%3a41%3a00-05%3a00">Factory / Production Operatives</a></td>
                        <td><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCompany">TipTopJob</span></td>
                        <td>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblArea">NW-ashton / under / lyne</span>
                    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCity"></span>
                </td>
                    </tr>
```

here is the jsoup part of the code am working on

```
titlee[i] = hrefElements.get(i).attr("href,td");<br>
titlee[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByAttribute("href").after("a.title").attr("title");
```

Comment: PLease wasted hours just help man cmon

Comment: You need to get the value form `a` not `href`

Comment: a.title ? or getElementsByAttribute("a").after("a.title").attr("title");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the anchors first and then you can select its text or attributes

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements a = doc.select("a");
    for(Element e : a) {
        String linkHref = e.attr("href");
        String linkText = e.text();
        System.out.println(linkHref + linkText);
    }
```

The `linkTExt` is the text of the anchor tag.

Comment: RP wow amazing very good, thank you sirr! solute you ,  one thing  i se is , its extracting other unwanted html , i only want to extract data from these row ,  as i posted the html above there are maybe max 20 row of them data 1 after another i just posted 1 part of the line to make it easy to work with here , the code you provided works very sweet it just grabs other unwanted links and texts which are not needed

Comment: Jsoup selectors are powerful, if you want to restrict based on a pattern, you could do so. See this http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: I added  `Elements a = doc.select("tr a[title]");`and now its doing what i want , i really want to thank **RP-** for helping me and i dont know what to say i really give you big big thank you and hug **rp** Thank you.

Comment: 1 more thing in the code you provided how do i also extract **TipTopJob**   & **NW-ashton / under / lyne** these 2 data i want to get also

Comment: No problem, glad that you have solved your problem. Regd second question, just like you are getting `a`s, like `Elements spans = doc.select("tr td span");` and iterate over them.

Comment: is it possible to extract all those info in 1 string , rather then having them create new line for each td , because all those information are for that job description.